# Change Table's Color With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I am trying change table's color from blue to red with JavaScript.

```
   function change(idElement){
  var element = document.getElementById(idElement);

    if(element.style.background = "#00BFFF")
        element.style.background = "#800000";


   else{
        element.style.background = "#00BFFF";
}

 }
```

This is my JavaScript code. It changes color one time, but I want to change its color again its old color when it is clicked.

Comment: In JavaScript equality signs are `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 2):

**First Problem - Assignment vs Equality**

Your first problem is that you are using an equals sign which is always assigning a value, rather than checking the value as a condition:

```
if(element.style.background = "#00BFFF")
```

should be

```
if(element.style.background === "#00BFFF")
```

**Second Problem - Normalized Color Formats**

The second problem is that in some browsers, you can set the background color of an element, but then when you query it, you will see it in a normalized format. For instance, in Chrome, if you open up the dev tools and run the following command `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"`, you will see the background turn red as you expect. However, if you immediately type `document.body.style.backgroundColor`, it will report the color in rgb format as `rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

Comment: If I change state to if(element.style.background === "#00BFFF"), it does not enter into if statement it is entering only else.

Comment: My point in the second problem is that the browser might not report the background color in the format you expect. You may very well have set it to "#00BFFF", but when you check the value, it could be "rgb(0, 191, 255)". Both represent the same color.